# DockerFile : Difference between ADD and COPY

Tags: docker

As per this the following reference about the [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#copy) instruction
I see no difference between `ADD` and `COPY`.
Please help me with a simple example explaining the difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker COPY vs ADD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958140/docker-copy-vs-add)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958140

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found the answer here: [Docker COPY vs ADD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958548/4039768)

- `ADD` instruction allows `<src>` to be an `URL`
- If the `<src>` parameter of `ADD` is an archive in a recognized compression format, it will be unpacked

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy

Answer (score 4):

From Docker online documentation :

```
ADD or COPY
```

> Although ADD and COPY are functionally similar, generally speaking, COPY is preferred. That’s because it’s more transparent than ADD. COPY only supports the basic copying of local files into the container, while ADD has some features (like local-only tar extraction and remote URL support) that are not immediately obvious. Consequently, the best use for ADD is local tar file auto-extraction into the image, as in ADD rootfs.tar.xz /.

More information can be found at [Best Practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#dockerfile-instructions)

Basically,

Use COPY for plain files and/or directories copy,

Use ADD for extracting TAR archives or downloading remote content,