# copying files using cp in dockfile fails

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to copy one file from one directory to another in an ubuntu image in a dockfile. I tried
`RUN cp make/A.mk ./B.mk 
RUN make -j4` 
But it failed. Anyone can help me fix the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the recommended method, in order to copy a file, you have

ADD
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

and

COPY
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

in a Dockerfile

see [What is the difference between the `COPY` and `ADD` commands in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958140/docker-copy-vs-add) for example