# Copy apps on docker jboss/wildfly images container

Tags: deployment, jboss, docker, containers, wildfly

copy the war file into wildfly images without extract the war file

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
ADD your-awesome-app.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

when i add my war file into the docker images the war file  auto extract. then make the wildfly service fail to start

what i gonna ask is how to add the war file without extract the war file

Answer (score 4):

Try using the COPY command, as opposed to ADD.

`COPY your-awesome-app.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/`

See the [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) and a helpful [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958548/4346927) that both discuss the subtle, yet important differences between COPY and ADD.

Comment: i already try ADD and COPY and the result same. it still auto extract the file

Answer (score 0):

i already found the answer

from this

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
ADD your-awesome-app.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

change to this

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
ADD your-awesome-app.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/your-awesome-app.war
```

and it will copy the extract file to the war file same as the file name