# Installation of sql relay fails

Tags: sql, linux, docker, installation

I just created a docker container and tried to install SQL Relay inside it.

I've checked the prerequisites [here](http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/sqlrelay/admin/prerequisites.html) and followed the installation documents [here](http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/sqlrelay/admin/installing.html#unixlinux).

However, at the end of `make install` of sqlrelay, I saw an error like this:

```
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/sqlrelay: file does not exist
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/sqlrcachemanager: file does not exist
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/sqlrelay-0.66.0/init'
make: *** [install-init] Error 2
```

What might be wrong with my installation?

Here's the docker file I used to start my installation:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install libxml2-dev libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libmysqld-dev -y

RUN apt-get install mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev -y

# sql relay prerequisites 
RUN apt-get install g++ make perl php5-dev python-dev ruby-dev \
tcl-dev openjdk-7-jdk erlang-dev nodejs-dev node-gyp mono-devel \
libmariadbclient-dev libpq-dev firebird-dev libfbclient2 libsqlite3-dev \
unixodbc-dev freetds-dev mdbtools-dev -y

COPY rudiments-0.56.0.tar.gz /
COPY sqlrelay-0.66.0.tar.gz /

EXPOSE 80
```

Here are the outputs of `./configure`, `make`, and `make install` inside sqlrelay-0.66.0 folder:

[configure_log](https://gist.github.com/lyenliang/f6db571ebdec44a3e3787d3f8327e757)

[make_log](https://gist.github.com/lyenliang/7e586578b42ab030ed44eb6388aea1a6)

[make_install_log](https://gist.github.com/lyenliang/9c348d04232579f10a88b604a1c96ea3)

If you need more information of my installation process, just let me know. I can provide it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `ADD` instead of `COPY` in your lines such as

`COPY rudiments-0.56.0.tar.gz /`

Your COPY just copies the .tar.gz, but does not unpack them

as with ADD

`If the <src> parameter of ADD is an archive in a recognised compression format, it will be unpacked`

This is extracted from

[What is the difference between the `COPY` and `ADD` commands in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958140/docker-copy-vs-add)

Comment: I type `tar -zxvf rudiments-0.56.0.tar.gz` to unpack the file manually.

Comment: I only automize part of the installation process because I'm not that familiar with docker.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently hit the same issue. The issue I found was that the init Makefile was incorrectly detecting the use of systemctl on Ubuntu Trusty and putting the scripts there. Later on the script would try to find the scripts in init.d and fail.

The solution is to edit the Makefile: `sqlrelay-X.X.X/init/Makefile`

Replace:

```
install:
    if ( test -d "/lib/systemd/system" ); \
```

With:

```
install:    
    if ( test -d "/lib/systemd/system_x" ); \
```

Make a similar change to the `uninstall` option later in the script and it will now correctly install on Ubuntu.