# docker run error: Unable to access jarfile

Tags: docker

Docker image is built but when I want to run it, it shows this error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile rest-service-1.0.jar
```

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and I use docker build -t doc-service & docker run doc-service.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER Frederico Apostolo <frederico.apostolo@blockfactory.com> (@fapostolo)

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade

RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties language-pack-en-base

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

RUN apt-get update && apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get -y --allow-downgrades --allow-remove-essential --allow-change-held-packages upgrade \
    && echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections \
    && apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades --allow-remove-essential --allow-change-held-packages curl vim unzip wget oracle-java8-installer \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/cache/* /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/

run java -version
run echo $JAVA_HOME

#use locate for debug
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locate mlocate && updatedb

#LIBREOFFICE START
RUN apt-get update && apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install -y -q libreoffice \
    libreoffice-writer ure libreoffice-java-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-common \
    fonts-opensymbol hyphen-fr hyphen-de hyphen-en-us hyphen-it hyphen-ru fonts-dejavu \
    fonts-dejavu-core fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-noto fonts-dustin fonts-f500 fonts-fanwood \
    fonts-freefont-ttf fonts-liberation fonts-lmodern fonts-lyx fonts-sil-gentium \
    fonts-texgyre fonts-tlwg-purisa
#LIBREOFFICE END

#font configuration
COPY 00-odt-template-renderer-fontconfig.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d

RUN mkdir /document-service /document-service/fonts /document-service/module /document-service/logs

# local settings
RUN echo "127.0.0.1       http://www.arbs.local http://arbs.local www.arbs.local arbs.local" >> /etc/hosts
# && mkdir /logs/ && echo "dummy" >> /logs/errors.log

#EXPOSE 2115

COPY document-service-java_with_user_arg.sh /
RUN chmod +x /document-service-java_with_user_arg.sh

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    ca-certificates \
    curl

RUN gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4
RUN curl -o /usr/local/bin/gosu -SL "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.4/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \
    && curl -o /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc -SL "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.4/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture).asc" \
    && gpg --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
    && rm /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu

ENV LANG="en_US.UTF-8"

# In case someone loses the Dockerfile
# Needs to be in the end so it doesn't invalidate unaltered cache whenever the file is updated.
RUN rm -rf /etc/Dockerfile
ADD Dockerfile /etc/Dockerfile

ENTRYPOINT ["/document-service-java_with_user_arg.sh"]

this is document-service-java_with_user_arg.sh:

#!/bin/bash

USER_ID=${LOCAL_USER_ID:-9001}
USER_NAME=${LOCAL_USER_NAME:-jetty}

echo "Starting user: $USER_NAME with UID : $USER_ID"
useradd --shell /bin/bash --home-dir /document-service/dockerhome --non-unique --uid $USER_ID $USER_NAME

cd /document-service

/usr/local/bin/gosu $USER_NAME "$@" java -jar rest-service-1.0.jar
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Looks like rest-service-1.0.jar is missing.  Add it to your container, package, and class path.

Comment: for debug, you can run `pwd` and `ll` / `dir` to check- location, where command runs (`/usr/local/bin/gosu $USER_NAME "$@" java -jar rest-service-1.0.jar`
), and content of the given folder, then you will at least know if the file is missing or inaccessible , and `pwd` will give you location, where its trying to find given file

Comment: rest-service-1.0.jar is placed in the same folder of dockerfile. How can I add it to my container, package, and class path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, you must add the JAR when building the image by defining in your Dockerfile :

```
COPY rest-service-1.0.jar /document-service/rest-service-1.0.jar
```

You could also just use :

```
COPY rest-service-1.0.jar /rest-service-1.0.jar
```

, and remove `cd /document-service` in your entrypoint script, as on `ubuntu:16.04` images, default working directory is `/`. My opinion is that setting the working directory in the script is safer, so you should just go for the first solution.

Note that you could also use `ADD` instead of `COPY` (as you already did in your `Dockerfile`), but here only `COPY` is necessary (read this post if you want more info : [What is the difference between the `COPY` and `ADD` commands in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958140/what-is-the-difference-between-the-copy-and-add-commands-in-a-dockerfile)).

Finally, I suggest you to add the `COPY` line at the end of your `Dockerfile`, so that if a new JAR is built, image won't be rebuilt from scratch but from an existing layer, speeding up build time.

Answer (score 0):

it looking error about workdir
you must select workdir for this copy format
try WORKDIR /yourpath/