# What executable path should I give for geckodriver when using docker?

Tags: python, docker

I have my `geckodriver` in the same directory as my `Dockerfile.`

I have tried setting the `executable_path` for my webdriver to `"./geckodriver"`, `"geckodriver"` and `"/app/geckodriver"`

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path="./geckodriver", firefox_profile=fp, capabilities=capabilities_argument)
```

I get this error message.

```
Could not find firefox in your system PATH. Please specify the binary location or install firefox
```

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.6

# Set buffered environment variable
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set the working directory to /app
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Install packacges needed for crontab and selenium
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo libpulse0 pulseaudio software-properties-common libappindicator1 fonts-liberation xserver-xephyr
RUN apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin cron nano -y

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
ADD requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /app/

# Run script
CMD ["./scrape.sh"]
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I have already tried it still no luck :( `"./geckodriver"` works locally though

Comment: Side note: it is best practice to use `COPY` rather than `ADD`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958140/what-is-the-difference-between-the-copy-and-add-commands-in-a-dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it couldn't identify **Firefox** in it's **PATH**, not the geckodriver. So you should install Firefox in your image `apt install firefox` or you can use [selenium/standalone-firefox image](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/tree/master/StandaloneFirefox)

Comment: @ConnorMcCann side note: in addition, you should export environment variable `MOZ_HEADLESS=1` before running the script (`scrape.sh`) to ensure that firefox runs in headless mode.