# Creating a dockerfile to compile source code

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to follow the 2 steps mentioned below:

1) Downloaded source code of

https://sourceforge.net/projects/hunspell/files/Hyphen/2.8/hyphen-2.8.8.tar.gz/download

2) Compiled it and you will get binary named example:

> hyphen-2.8.8$ ./example ~/dev/smc/hyphenation/hi_IN/hyph_hi_IN.dic
>   ~/hi_sample.text

I have downloaded and uncompressed the tar file. My question is how to create a dockerfile to automate this?

There are only 3 commands involved:

```
./configure
make all-recursive
make install
```

I can select the official python image as a base container. But how do I write the commands in a docker file?

Comment: The link you posted automatically downloaded some `tar.gz` file from `sourceforge.net`. You might want to change that link so it points to the download page. I'm sure I am not the only person that is very distrusting of anything coming from sourceforge.

Comment: If you use ADD dont forget to unzip the tar file. Else you can also use copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a `RUN` command:

```
FROM python:<version number here>

RUN ./configure && make-recursive && make install

CMD ['<some command here>']
```

what you use for `<some command here>` depends on what the image is meant to do. Remember that docker containers only run as long as that command is executing, so if you put the `configure/make/install` steps in a script and use that as your entry point, it's going to build your program, and then the container will halt.

Also you need to get the downloaded files into the container. That can be done using a `COPY` or an `ADD` directive (before the `RUN` of course). If you have the `tar.gz` file saved locally, then `ADD` will both copy the file into the container *and* expand it into a directory automatically. `COPY` will not expand it, so if you do that, you'll need to add a `tar -zxvf` or similar to the `RUN`.

If you want to download the file directly into the container, that could be done with `ADD <source URL>`, but in that case it won't expand it, so you'll have to do that in the `RUN`. `COPY` doesn't allow sourcing from a URL. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958140/what-is-the-difference-between-the-copy-and-add-commands-in-a-dockerfile) explains `COPY` vs `ADD` in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the three commands in a shell script and then use the following docker commands

```
COPY ./<path to your script>/<script-name>.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/<script-name>.sh"]
CMD ["run"]
```

For reference, you can create your docker file as they have created for one of the projects I worked on Apache ActiveMQ Artemis:
https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-docker/Dockerfile-ubuntu

Comment: You'd almost always run commands like `make install` while the image is being built (in a `RUN` command) and not when the image is starting up (as the image's `ENTRYPOINT`).