# What is the use of ADD keyword inside Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

What is the use of below mentioed `ADD` statements in `Dockerfile`?

```
ADD file:fe7ce7130f4def5281d26a00a6153276183249e6c5d5923e2e9c80e6527e309f in .
ADD file:586f39849d652b9e8266f7368569f345bc7d59cee2abb9d6747b4795b744bc2e in .
RUN /bin/sh -c : '==== make the notebooks convenient to access and have the right date'
```

Comment: That looks like `docker history` output, not something you'd see in a `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between the 'COPY' and 'ADD' commands in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958140/what-is-the-difference-between-the-copy-and-add-commands-in-a-dockerfile)

Comment: @DavidMaze  Thanks for the direction ..Now I can dig more around it.

Comment: @Bee I can use the post shared by  you and then do a history to understand.. Thank you for directions