# Docker doesn't see main.go

Tags: docker, go, microservices

I have some problems with Docker. My dockerfile doesn't see main.go.
I have that struct project

```
docker-compose.yml  
go.mod
frontend-microservice  
  -cmd  
    -app
      -main.go
  -internal
    -some folders
```

When I try start docker-compose It's give me that error.

```
ERROR: Service 'frontend-microservice' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix nocgo -o /frontend-microservice .' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

By the way dockerfile give error related to go.mod

That my docker-compose

```
version: "3"
services:
    frontend-microservice:
        build:    
            context: ./frontend-microservice/
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - 80:80
```

That my dockerfile

```
# golang image where workspace (GOPATH) configured at /go.
FROM golang:alpine as builder

ADD . /go/src/frontend-microservice
WORKDIR /go/src/frontend-microservice
RUN go mod download

COPY . ./

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix nocgo -o /frontend-microservice .

FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
 
COPY --from=builder /frontend-microservice ./frontend-microservice
RUN mkdir ./configs 
COPY ./configs/config.json ./configs
 
EXPOSE 8080
 
ENTRYPOINT ["./frontend-microservice"]
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: your main file is in frontend-microservice/cmd/app; and seems you are running build command in frontend-microservice

Comment: add `cd cmd/app` before the `go build`

Comment: P.S. don't use [ADD - use COPY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958548/1218512) instead.

Comment: @colm.anseo thx, now I can try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file where the `main()` function is defined is located in `cmd/app`.
Instead of changing the current working directory into `cmd/app`, append `cmd/app/main.go` to the `go build` command.

Your `Dockerfile` would look like this:

```
# golang image where workspace (GOPATH) configured at /go.
FROM golang:alpine as builder

ADD . /go/src/frontend-microservice
WORKDIR /go/src/frontend-microservice
RUN go mod download

COPY . ./

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix nocgo -o /frontend-microservice cmd/app/main.go

FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
 
COPY --from=builder /frontend-microservice ./frontend-microservice
RUN mkdir ./configs 
COPY ./configs/config.json ./configs
 
EXPOSE 8080
 
ENTRYPOINT ["./frontend-microservice"]
```

Comment: tnx, for ur help