# can't run cron message inside alpine docker file

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, cron

I'm trying to launch a simple chron message inside a docker container to test chron :

Inside my php-fpm Dockerfile :

```
...

RUN echo "*       *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/1min" >> /etc/crontabs/root

RUN mkdir /etc/periodic/1min

COPY cronscript.sh /etc/periodic/1min

RUN chmod a+x /etc/periodic/1min/cronscript.sh

RUN dos2unix /etc/periodic/1min/cronscript.sh

...

CMD [ "crond", "-l", "2", "-f" ]; composer install ; wait-for-it database:3306 -- bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate ;  php-fpm;
```

My cronscript.sh :

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo "My test message"
```

When i run `crontab -e` inside the container i got :

[image]

When i run the container i didn't get the message :

[image]

How can i correctly show the message periodically each 1 minute ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that cron jobs are added to the schedule?

1. Try to define your jobs outside of the Docker image like `cron.txt`

   ```
   * * * * * xxx xxx
   ```
2. Add the schedule to the image using `ADD` command in Dockerfile

   ```
   ADD cron.txt /etc/crontabs/xxx
   ```

Comment: hello, inside my docker file i use this command : RUN echo "*       *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/1min" >> /etc/crontabs/root, and the i copy the script inside the 1min folder,  should i copy the cript outside the docker image?

Comment: Yes.
In case if you want to add a custom file to the docker image you should use ADD or COPY docker command (here is the difference between them https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958548/6916890).

Comment: In my case it works, the app in production for more than 4 years. Please ensure that jobs are placed in the proper location using ADD command, and cron itself started in ENTRYPOINT/CMD.

Comment: how can i verify that cron itself started in ENTRYPOINT/CMD please

Answer (score 0):

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine

# Copy script which should be run
COPY ./yourscript /usr/local/bin/yourscript
# Run the cron every minute
RUN echo '*  *  *  *  *    /usr/local/bin/yourscript' > /etc/crontabs/root

CMD ['crond', '-l 2', '-f']
```

`Script`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "My test message" >> /dev/stdout
```

Comment: hello, this line was added to my crontab, when i run crontab -e i got this line : *  *  *  *  *    /usr/local/bin/script , but i didn't get any message, look like the cron doesn't work