# Running Maven test in Docker container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, maven

I have a Spring boot application in a Docker container and when I run the command to execute tests I see that the app starts correctly but there is no test executed. Looks like the `mvn test` is completely ignored.

Below my docker commands:

```bash
docker build -t cygnetops/react-test -f Dockerfile.dev .
docker  run  cygnetops/react-test mvn test
```

*Dockerfile.dev*

```bash
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD /target/demoCI-CD-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]

EXPOSE 5000
```

Comment: Do the tests run with mvn on your local machine outside of your ide?

Comment: When having both a cmd and an entrypoint, the cmd is passed to the entrypoint. If the entrypoint does nothing with it, it makes sense it is ignored.

Comment: Yes the issue looks like that the command is passed to the entrypoint and ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entrypoints and commands are working together in a Docker container, if you specify an entrypoint, your command will be passed as an argument to the entrypoint, and if that entrypoint does nothing with the arguments passed to it, then the behaviour you are observing it totally normal.

The chapter "*[Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact)*" of the documentation provides a nice table explaining in depth how they interact.

In order to run you tests from that image, you could override the entrypoint when running you container:

```bash
docker run --entrypoint "" cygnetops/react-test mvn test
```

*Note*:

1. you will also have to install Maven, as it is not part of your base image
2. as you pointed, you will also need the POM and files of the Java project in order to run the tests, so you need to copy those sources in the image

So, add, in your *Dockerfile*, the lines:

```bash
COPY . .

RUN apk add --no-cache maven
```

---

If you want both to work, on the other hand, you will have to write your own entrypoint and make something from the command passed as arguments.

Here is an example:
*entrypoint.sh*, should be located at the same level as your *Dockerfile*:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

exec "$@" # execute what is passed as argument

java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
```

Then, for your *Dockerfile*

```bash
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp

RUN apk add --no-cache maven

COPY . .
COPY /target/demoCI-CD-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 5000
```

Comment: Tried but get this: docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "mvn": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Comment: well... you have to install `mvn` too, as it is not part of that image, then.

Comment: @StefanoMaglione steps to do that added in an edit.

Comment: I had to add also "ADD . . " in order to load all pom and files in the image for maven test to run

Comment: Rather use [`COPY` than `ADD`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958140/what-is-the-difference-between-the-copy-and-add-commands-in-a-dockerfile).

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: @StefanoMaglione follow the link in the comment

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better solution is to create a docker file that runs a script instead of plain java. for example create a runner.sh file as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD="java -jar app.jar"
$CMD &
SERVICE_PID=$!
mvn test
wait "$SERVICE_PID"
```

and this will be your dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.9.0-eclipse-temurin-11-alpine
COPY . .
RUN mvn install
COPY runner.sh /scripts/runner.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/scripts/runner.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/scripts/runner.sh"]
```

Comment: Bash is not part of an Alpine distribution, so, you will most likely get an error from that shebang.