# How to set the project path in the COPY attribute in WSL

Tags: linux, docker, window, windows-subsystem-for-linux, opera

[I got some 'return non zero code :1' error in console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRu8D.png)

I am new to Docker. I got this error in WSL when trying to build [Dockerfile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)#Tools) on WSL. I got some path error. How can I fix it?

I have already set to path here like:

```
COPY /users/home/project/docker_sample_web_app/docker_sample_web_app /docker_sample_web_app
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please [see the reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933) we ask that you not add images of text messages/code/etc. to your posts.  Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76958531/edit) your post to include the text of the message, along with the text of any applicable configurations.  I've provided you an example of how it should be formatted to be more readable.  Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Isn't COPY [a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958140/what-is-the-difference-between-the-copy-and-add-commands-in-a-dockerfile), not an attribute?

Comment: Why is it tagged with "Opera"?